# How to run filesystemwatcher's "onchanged" event multiple times at the same time?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, filesystemwatcher

My question is about the following:

I'm using a `FileSystemWatcher` which is raising a method when the file is changed(the machine is writing to the file). I'm trying to raise this method again even if the previous hasn't finished its job(I stopped the thread with a `MessageBox` and I just don't press OK). The problem is that, the `OnChanged` event hasn't been raised again when the file changes, but the previous thread is not finished.

The watching of the folder is running on a separate thread as I know well. c

```
public Mainform()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   //....
   fileSystemWatcher1.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(start_thread);
   //....
}
```

When it changes, runs the following method, this is what I tried, but doesn't work.

```
    private void start_thread(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() => OnChanged(source, e));
        if (System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("thread").Length == 0)
        {
            Thread thread2 = new Thread(() => OnChanged(source, e));
            thread2.Name = "thread2";
            thread2.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            thread.Start();
            thread.Name = "thread";
        }
    }
```

It raises the `OnChanged` event which looks like this:

```
private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Something.");
}
```

Comment: depending on the `NotifyFilter` you have set and the inner shortcomings of `FileSystemWatcher`, like flooding or missing events, starting a thread for each event handler looks overkill. You could gather events in some parallel, non-blocking collection and consume from there. You could even skip duplicates if arrival time frame is less than some delta interval.

Comment: Use a debugger breakpoint or Debug.Print() to debug code, *never* MessageBox.  You have no guarantee whatsoever that you'll see it, a dialog like MessageBox requires an owner window to function reliably.  If it doesn't then you can't easily see when two of them overlap or it appear underneath another window.